# How to create different shapes and fill color in them?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am creating a form on which there is a circle on the form and inside this circle I want to add different shapes(user defined) and then fill those shapes with different colors.

- Sometimes all the shapes are circles.
- Sometimes there are circles and Polygons.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: So, can these shapes be arbitrary polygons?

Comment: Not exactly the polygon
Unspecified shapes is the better word to describe them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows Forms then you're almost certainly going to be using GDI+ to do your drawing.  You'll handle the `Paint` event of the appropriate control and use the `Graphics` object provided by the `e.Graphics` property to do your drawing or else call `Graphics.FromImage` to produce a `Graphics` object to draw onto an `Image` object.

You should check out the documentation for that `Graphics` class and its methods whose names begin with "Draw" and, particularly, "Fill".  It provides a few predefined, regular shapes and then lets you create your own shapes using an array of `Point` values to define the vertices of a polygon or a `GraphicsPath` or the like.